# Setblock command not working in Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to use NPCs, and I need to remove the redstone block activating one of the command blocks, I have it set to `/setblock -394 59 239` and no matter how I use it (chain, impulse, conditional, unconditional, always active, needs redstone) or even where I put it, it's saying

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected "": 394 59 239>><<<
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to put in the specific block you want set, right?

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment is saying, you did not fill in the block parameter.

In other words, `/setblock ~ ~ ~ stone` would work.